# Displaying the form if the post is empty or result if it has already been submitted

Tags: php, forms, post, reload

This is my first post and I'm complete beginner so please be gentle :) 
I'm trying to create a form that after submitting an account name would check and return a CNAME of the host (account+domain.com) 
The problem is that I want to do it all on the same website so it will either display the form if nothing has been posted or display the result otherwise.  
This is what I've created, it seems that I'm not calling the POST correctly, but I can't really get what am I doing wrong.  
Please help

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST[DomainSubmit])){
$AccountName = $_POST[ClientDomain];
$CName = dns_get_record($AccountName."domain.com", DNS_CNAME);
echo '<h1>'.$CName.'<h1>';
}


echo'<form action="index.php" method="POST" ">
<input type="text" name="ClientDomain">
<input type="submit" name="DomainSubmit">
</form>'
?>
```

Comment: Do you want an `else` before echoing the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add else so it will be displayed one or another stuff

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['DomainSubmit']) && isset($_POST['ClientDomain'])){
    $AccountName = $_POST['ClientDomain'];
    $CName = dns_get_record($AccountName."domain.com", DNS_CNAME);
    echo '<h1>'.$CName.'<h1>';
} else {
    echo'<form action="index.php" method="POST" ">
            <input type="text" name="ClientDomain">
            <input type="submit" name="DomainSubmit">
         </form>'
}
?>
```

Edit:
You forgot to properly write array POST (missing quotes)

```
$_POST[DomainSubmit]
```

And it should be

```
$_POST['DomainSubmit']
```

Comment: Yeah that's correct, thanks for noticing but it does not help with the problem I'm having. After loading  I receive error:
Notice: Use of undefined constant DomainSubmit - assumed 'DomainSubmit'

Comment: ohh sec let me try to fix it